# How can I make a motor powered hammer swing more naturally than a Leonardo cam?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors

Most people are probably familiar with [Leonardo hammer cams](https://gfycat.com/boldwellmadeiberianmidwifetoad). But I'd like to make a motor-powered hammer that swings more like this (apologies for the crude diagram):
[image]

The hammer would fall due to gravity, then get dragged along the ground on its way back up.

Of course, this diagram does not work, because the hammer on the way up needs to make a >= 90 degree angle with the wheel radius in order to fall (step 2), but needs to collapse to < 90 degrees in step 4 in order to drag along the ground.

Is this doable with simple, hardware store components?

Comment: Why do this - the link shows a system that uses much less energy   ie the distance the hammer has to be moved.

Comment: it’s for an art project

Comment: Have look at the motion here : https://youtu.be/n-2YN_Ak9eE

Comment: This is called a flail. It is often just a head on a length of chain fixed to a wheel.[flail mower](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SnhKsPKF-Q), [excavator flail](https://www.skidsteersolutions.com/40ex-hd-excavator-brush-flail-mower-rockhound/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI86axkezw4QIVEYGzCh0u3AT6EAQYBSABEgJzn_D_BwE), [tank flail](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpeflBfxXzY)

Comment: @Solar Mike yes that's exactly the motion I would love to recreate

Comment: @Phil is there a diagram of this you know of? It's not clear from the videos how I would make this

Answer (score 1):

It may work if you modify the legs of the handles properly and possibly allow a bit of vertical play in the axis of the wheel.

Just as an alternative you can put the hammer passing straight through a spring loaded sleeved hole in the disk.
here is a sketch.

-

[image]

Comment: Ah ok, just to clarify by "ally vertical play" -- you mean when the hammer is dragged on the ground, another motor raises the wheel? If so that makes sense.

Can you explain a bit more what you mean by having a spring loaded sleved hole in the disk?

Comment: I draw a sketch later. But if you could imagine just a straight long handle passing through a drilled bushing with pre loaded spring to give it a jerk at the right moment. I will modify my answer. I meant allow not Ally. Sorry.

Comment: Would love to see a sketch, thank you

Comment: @neptune, I added my sketch. hope it clarifies my point.